# how to get relation data of model with another name of foreighkey in laravel?

Tags: laravel

There are 2 models. Team and Player. The team has many players and the Player belongsTo a Team.

this is player migration:

```
$table->foreignId('team')->constrained('teams');
```

and relation:

```
   public function team(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Team::class);
    }
```

if I use:

```
$table->foreignId('team_id')->constrained();
```

The query result is ok and I can get the name of the player team as:

```
$team = Player::find(1)->team->name;
```

but I want to use "team' in migration instead of "team_id" and I change the foreignkey in relation  as:

```
   public function team(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Team::class, 'team');
    }
```

with migration:

```
$table->foreignId('team')->constrained('teams');
```

but I cant get the name of the player team.

Comment: I think the issue is that in your case, `$player->team` can be either the model `Team` or the column `team` (ID). I don't think both can co-exists with the same name.

Comment: As far i understand you want to change the team_id(foreign key) to team. If that's correct you can try this way.

`public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class, 'foreign_key', 'owner_key');
}`

@Mehdi Yaghoubi

Comment: `team_id` is the better name for the column, as it follows both Laravel and SQL naming convention. Is there any reason you want to use `team` over `team_id` as the column name? Feels like you're working against yourself here... Clement is completely correct in that the column and method name are the same, so resolution of `$player->team`  is ambiguous.

Comment: @TimLewis: I need two columns "Home" and "Away" concerning the same team's table. so, I need to have two different names for the same relation id (team_id)

Comment: Then you'd use something like `home_team_id`, and `away_team_id`. Your relationships would be `public function homeTeam() { return $this->belongsTo(Team::class, 'home_team_id'); }` and `public function awayTeam() { return $this->belongsTo(Team::class, 'away_team_id'); }`. Voila! Multiple relationships to the same model with different names but still following convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You relation name `team` is as same as the attribute name `team`, so the `$player->team` gets the team ID not the relation, you may try `getRelationValue` method:

```php
$player->team // gets team ID
$player->getRelationValue('team') // gets the team relation
$player->getRelationValue('team')->name // is what you want
```

Comment: Thank you. I changed the relation name to "tim" and worked correctly.